# Subsurface modifier creates gaps on extrude

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

So, when using a subsurface modifier, it always creates a kind of gap between the main structure and the extrueded one. I never know why.. here's how it looks like:
[image]

Anybody knows how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because has a face betweeen those. You need to delete that face.However this is not a normal behavior.